# destructure only if object is defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

How can I destructure an object only if it is defined ?

```
const {url} = image; // only destructure if image is defined.
                    // don't want to nest the destructuring in if image condition
```

Comment: `if (image) { const {url} = image; }`

Comment: do you mean only if defined or declared?

Answer (score 3):

If by saying

> only destructure if image is **defined**

You mean that it is declared for sure, then you can do this:

```
const {url} = image || {};
```

Running Examples:

```js
let image;
const {url} = image || {};

console.log('url is',url);
```

```js
const image = {url: 'someUrl.com'};
const {url} = image || {};

console.log('url is', url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The target has to be at least declared:

```js
let image;
const { url } = image ? image : {}; // undefined
console.log(url)
```

```js
let image = { url: '/some/path' };
const { url } = image ? image : {};
console.log(url)
```